# Submit a specific approval process from a Flow

Tags: process-builder, flow

I am attempting to launch a specific approval process using a Flow. Although this feature is documented, it does not appear to be working as advertised. Here is my setup:

- I have three active Approval Processes
- I would like to submit the third process in the list on button click
- My flow is set up like this:

[image]

- When I launch the flow from a URL button, it always submits the *first* approval process.
- I have tried using the Approval Process name with and without underscores, using the Approval Process Id, and have tried all with and without quotations.

Also worth noting, when I attempt the same exact thing via Process Builder, it submits my third approval process, and works as expected:

[image]

Unfortunately, I can't use the Process Builder since I need the approval process to be submitted via button click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a very simple mistake on my part. I had created a custom button called 'Submit for Approval'. This custom button was not added to my page layout. However, the *default* 'Submit for Approval' button already existed on my page layout. I had the default and my custom buttons mixed up. As soon as I added my button to the layout, I got the results that were expected.